# pySpark .reduceByKey(min)/max weird behavior

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following function:

```
minTotal = numRDD.reduceByKey(min).collect()
maxTotal = numRDD.reduceByKey(max).collect()
```

A sample from my dataset that is acting strangely:

```
(18, [u'300.0', u'1000.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'1000.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0', u'300.0']
```

The min is reported as: 1000
and Max as 300

Very odd to me all my other key/values are reporting correctly except for this one. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: I think `1000` as a string is less than `300` (as a string). I understand why you think it is strange, but this is the expected imho.

Comment: Oh so convert them to float() first, I didnt even notice that.

Comment: You should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot that they are unicode and they will be evaluating as strings not their numeric form. So you need to convert to float to get the correct answer.